# How to write: $wpdb->update having WHERE NOT value pair in the array

Tags: query, wpdb, array

I need to update all meta keys in the postmeta table that have a value other than 0, to the value of 0.

I tried this.. no love (though I cannot figure out why....):

```
$status = $wpdb->query("UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta SET meta_value=0 WHERE meta_key = _wti_like_count AND meta_value <> '0'");
```

I'm on this concept, but how to say "!0" NOT 0 in the key list?

```
$wpdb->update('wp_postmeta', array('_wti_like_count' => '0'), array('_wti_like_count' => '0'));
```

Thanks a ton!

UPDATE:  I fixed my `$wpdb->query` as follows and it works:

```
$status = $wpdb->query("UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta SET meta_value='0' WHERE meta_key = '_wti_like_count' AND meta_value <> '0'");
```

However, I would still like to know if there is a way to pass a key pair array to the `WHERE` parameter of `$wpdb->update` and request a `!=` value.

Comment: I don't have an answer yet... ?  I have a workaround that doesn't answer the question being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The `$wpdb` class properties

You can use *all* the default WordPress tables like this:

- `$GLOBALS['wpdb']->postmeta`

so no need to use `prefix`, etc.

### `meta_query`

As you can see from the [Custom field parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) documentation, there's nothing like the `<>` (or in other words: "not equal to") operator. The equivalent operator in WP *should be* `!=` (human words: "not is") or `NOT LIKE`.

So simply do something along the following lines:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_wti_like_count',
            'value'   => '0',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
            # 'type'    => 'numeric'
        )
    )
) );
```

This would query all your posts with this meta value. What makes me wonder is why you got a `string` as an `integer`. I wouldn't do that, especially not if I use a counter. See what I commented out: The `type`, which would allow you - later on - much more specific queries.

### Update the meta entries

Then simply loop through them and update the values.

```
if ( $query->have_posts() )
{
    while ( $query->have_posts() )
    {
        $query->the_post();
        # Do debugging, logging or sleep() here to avoid timeouts
        update_post_meta( '_wti_like_count', '0', true );

        # I still believe it should be an INTeger
        update_post_meta( '_wti_like_count', 0, true );
    }
}
```

Comment: This was very interesting!  About the str vs int portion, the reason I typed it as a string was because in the %postmeta table, the meta_value field is of the data type: LONGTEXT.  So I typed the data to that.  I figured I could just cast the data type either from the SQL or PHP into the needed type.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like it is possible to use != in the where. Here is the relevant code from the `update()` method:

```
$where_formats = $where_format = (array) $where_format;
foreach ( (array) array_keys( $where ) as $field ) {
    if ( !empty( $where_format ) )
        $form = ( $form = array_shift( $where_formats ) ) ? $form : $where_format[0];
    elseif ( isset( $this->field_types[$field] ) )
        $form = $this->field_types[$field];
    else
        $form = '%s';
    $wheres[] = "`$field` = {$form}";
}
```

The `$wheres[]` line is telling. It shows only `=` is ever used. That array is used later:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `$table` SET " . implode( ', ', $bits ) . ' WHERE ' . implode( ' AND ', $wheres );
```

In your case, the query could have worked without checking for the value not being `0`. The result would have been the same (though more rows would have been affected), but it looks like this method is limited to only `=` in the WHERE clauses.

Comment: Thank you Charles.  I kind of figured this was the case considering the semantics of the setup, but I was hoping someone with a bit more knowledge of the $wpdb object could help me out.  Thanks for filling me in!  
  
I guess I'll stick to hand writing the query's, it's what I'm used to anyways :)

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter( 'query', 'query_report', 10000 );
function query_report($sql){ 
    var_dump($sql); 
    return $sql;
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?